# disk read-only after upgrade 17.04 -> 17.10

Tags: upgrade, disk, read-only

I updated from Lubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 using "do-dist-upgrade". After the first two re-boots everything was fine. However, after I re-booted the system the third time some days later, it did not open the graphical environment, but a shell because it mounted the file system read-only. When re-mounting the file system in rw mode, the graphical environment loads automatically. But since then, this issue happens every start.

I did not found any hint to this issue in dmesg nor in /var/log/syslog. My internet research did not help me either. The resources dealing with this issue seem pretty rare. The device UUID as found in /dev/disk/by-/uuid is identical to that one found in /etc/fstab.

This issue temporarily solved when I deleted a link in /usr/lib which I created after the second re-boot after the installation because I wanted to make use of the -lcblas compiler flag in g++. However, this did not resolve the issue just for one re-boot.

Can you help me? If you need further information (e.g., log files), I'll provide them.

Best regards,
Green

Comment: Hi Green, did you solve this? I am having issues post 17.04 -> 17.10 also

Comment: Hi dibs, unfortunately, I didn't resolve it. You can re-mount the disk using the console line after boot, so you'll have a usable system. But you have to do this after each restart because the disk is always mounted read-only again. Log messages do not show anything special. Now, I'm just waiting for 18.04 to come, so I'll set up a completely clean system and definitely won't upgrade for the next 2 years.

Comment: Short note: after 18.04 was released, I did the dist-upgrade again and that solved the above mentioned issue. However, various other issues the system had after the update to 17.10 (randomly freezing and forgetting about the WiFi card) still were there.